# foreign key always stays null

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql2o

I need a bit of assistance in getting a connection between my two tables

These are the tables where "idPatient is the foreign key"
[image]

I fill the table "tanden" like this

```
public void addTandenToDatabase(int id, int fdi, String voorstelling, String toestand) {
    String insertSql = "insert into tanden(id, fdi, voorstelling, toestand) values (:idVal, :fdiVal, :voorstellingVal, :toestandVal)";
    try (Connection con = sql2o.open()) {
        con.setRollbackOnException(false);
        con.createQuery(insertSql)
                .addParameter("idVal", id)
                .addParameter("fdiVal", fdi)
                .addParameter("voorstellingVal", voorstelling)
                .addParameter("toestandVal", toestand)
                .executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Everything is added nicely but the idPatient stays null

[image]

Comment: idPatient is not included among values of your INSERT query. You don't specify it. Are you expecting to retrieve it automatically someway?

Comment: yeah, but how do i specify it

Comment: You need to have a patienten inserted at least. Then, knowing its id, use it as value for idPatient's column in tanden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include `idPatient` in your `insert` if you want to set value to it. 'foreign key' doesnot mean that it will be set value automically.

Comment: if i try to insert somthing in a foreign key i get this: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.sql2o.Sql2oException: Error in executeUpdate, Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`toondoesselaere`.`tanden`, CONSTRAINT `id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `patienten` (`idPatient`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert idPatient column value into tanden table by taking from patienten table.

Answer (score 1):

Your id column in the tanden table should be set as primary key and autoincrement and you have to set the idPatient in your insert

```
insert into tanden(idPatient, fdi, voorstelling, toestand) values(:idVal,:fdiVal, :voorstellingVal, :toestandVal)";
```

(The idPatient you set in the child table already has to exist in the parent table